# An agency or company who will help you

Tags: british-english, relative-pronouns

I know that "which" or "that" should be used to refer to entities, and "who" to people. However, I have come across "who" being used to refer to companies and agencies in a UK ESL textbook for the second time.

So is the following sentence grammatical in **UK English**?

> An agency or a company *who* will help you ...

Comment: What is the rest of the sentence?

Comment: The use of *who* is possible in BrE.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100607/is-it-a-company-who-makes-or-a-company-that-makes, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138110/who-or-which-in-reference-to-companies.

Answer (score 1):

Since an agency or company can't really do much without people, the use of *who* is logical, possibly if the speaker/writer wants to make the agency/company seem a bit friendlier to the listener/reader, or if the agency/company consists of only a few people.